# OpenCV Python: Convert RGB to YCrCb

Tags: python, opencv

I can't seem to convert RGB to YCrCb in the new OpenCV python API (cv2). When I run this code:

```
img = cv2.imread('img1.jpg')
imgYCC = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2YCrCb)
```

, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'COLOR_RGB2YCrCb'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The attribute is `CV_RGB2YCrCb`, not `COLOR_RGB2YCrCb`

Comment: In python it's different than other languages. For example, `COLOR_RGB2LAB` works fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The attribute name is `COLOR_RGB2YCR_CB` for RGB ordering.

Bear in mind that OpenCV natively uses BGR color ordering, not RGB, in which case the attribute is `COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB`. So, you may want to modify your code:

```
img = cv2.imread('img1.jpg')
imgYCC = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB)
```

Comment: Regardless of what OpenCV uses natively, .jpg images are RGB.

Comment: @martineau Interesting observation. Just for clarification: `cv2.imread()` loads color images into memory with BGR channel ordering, even if the file format specifies otherwise.

Comment: @Aurelius: Hmmm, I wonder why then they have different source colorspace conversion constants if it's always going to be from BGR?

Comment: @martineau It may not always be from BGR. There are other ways of getting an image into memory, and these may have a different color space, hence the multiple source formats. Not to mention having the ability to freely convert between color spaces as one may require.

Comment: In that case it might make more sense to use one of those "other ways" to get the natively RGB .jpg image into memory in that format and then do just one colorspace conversion rather than doing two of them.

Comment: And just to save some entropy due to an additional google search, you can `imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(imgYCC, cv2.COLOR_YCR_CB2BGR)` to convert the image back to RGB space